# Apply separately many JMS serialization groups on the same function

Tags: symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm looking for a feature with [jms_serliazer](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle).
Ok let me explain, suppose we have a function `getArticlesAction()`, and a `query param` called `group` that gonna represent the **group serialization name**.
So, after getting the name of serialization group `$paramFetcher->get ('group')`, Is it possible to apply serliazer group, eather *group1* or *group2*, based on that query param already recuperated ?

This is my example:

```
/**
 * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="group")
 */
public function getArticlesAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $groupName = $paramFetcher->get('group');

    //yourlogic
}
```

This is a part of my configuration under Entity.Article.yml, it's responsible for how the serliazation gonna be.

```
ArticleBundle\Entity\Article:
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
            groups: [group1, group2]
        name:
            expose: true
            serialized_name: name
            groups: [group1]
        label:
            expose: true
            serialized_name: label
            groups: [group2]
```

Here in my example, if we apply the *group1*, we gonna get a collections of objects with **(id, name)** keys, and if we apply the *group2*, then we gonna get a collections of objects with **(id, label)** keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the group come in via the parameter, assuming validation that it was a a valid group name, you could do this:

In the use section of the class, add:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Then the method would be:

```
/**
* @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="group")
*/
public function getArticlesAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $groupName = $paramFetcher->get('group');

    //snip - get the repo here
    $article = $articleRepo->find($articleId);
    $response = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($article, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups([$groupName]));

    return new Response($response, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replaying, seems great idea, i appreceate? and are you sur the serializer service gonna detect my Entity.Article.yml ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax of your yml file, I usually use annotations, but it can't be far off.

Comment: Yes true i will try tomorow morning then i will accept your answer.